# V3 flagging real visitors

Tags: recaptcha-v3

I implemented Recaptcha V3 on one of my sites, however, the results are very mixed. I added it to donation forms. I was able to implement OK, but some of our donors/vistors and even people in my office got flagged as spam this way.

One aspect of our donation pages is that visitors are driven to a single donation page under our domain and there isnt any user interaction prior - could this be causing these visitors to get flagged?  Is so why isnt it across the board?  or could it be something else I am not aware of?

I have set the score level to >= 1.0.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake - setting is >= 0.1

Answer (score 0):

you can use a threshold of 0.5.
Read the ***Interpreting the score*** section in this document https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3